# Comprobación de existencia de usuario C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenos días estoy tratando de validar, la existencia de usuario, un ejemplo seria tengo un textbox y cuando escriba el nombre de algún **usuario** me tiene que mostrar una imagen cargadas con **Properties.Resources**. Si el usuario existe me muestra un **check bueno**, entonces se activan unos textbox y si **no existe** me muestra un imagen correspondiente que **no existe.**

El problema esta que, cuando escribo un usuario existente me sale bien el check, pero si escribo uno que no existe no me sale la imagen les muestro el codigo, ocupo el evento **TextChanged**.

```
    private void txt_usuario_codigo_de_asociado_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable Dt = BLS.ExistenciaDeUsuario(txt_usuario_codigo_de_asociado.Text);

            foreach (DataRow Row in Dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Row["Usuario"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    Bitmap Img = Properties.Resources._002_checked1;

                    pbx_1.Image = Img;

                    txt_nueva_contraseña.Visible = true;
                    txt_repita_contraseña.Visible = true;
                    pbx_2.Visible = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    Bitmap Img = Properties.Resources._001_x_button;

                    pbx_1.Image = Img;

                    txt_nueva_contraseña.Visible = false;
                    txt_repita_contraseña.Visible = false;
                    pbx_2.Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Este codigo es donde hago la comprobacion del usuario

```
    public DataTable ExistenciaDeUsuario(string Usuario)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConexionBD))
        {
            Conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT
                                                            usuario
                                                        FROM
                                                            tb_usuario
                                                        WHERE
                                                            usuario = @usuario", Conn))
            {
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", Usuario);
                MySqlDataAdapter Dta = new MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
                DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
                Dta.Fill(Dt);
                return Dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola creo que el codigo del evento esta mal.

Yo haría esto:

```
private void txt_usuario_codigo_de_asociado_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//SUPONGO QUE ESTE ES EL CODIGO PARA MOSTRAR EL CODIGO CUANDO NO EXISTE EL USUARIO
    Bitmap Img = Properties.Resources._001_x_button;
    pbx_1.Image = Img;
    txt_nueva_contraseña.Visible = false;
    txt_repita_contraseña.Visible = false;
    pbx_1.Visible = true;

    try
      {
       DataTable Dt = BLS.ExistenciaDeUsuario txt_usuario_codigo_de_asociado.Text);

       foreach (DataRow Row in Dt.Rows)
            {
            if (Row["Usuario"].ToString() != null)
                {
                Bitmap Img = Properties.Resources._002_checked1;
                pbx_1.Image = Img;
                txt_nueva_contraseña.Visible = true;
                txt_repita_contraseña.Visible = true;
                pbx_1.Visible = true;
                break;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así

```
public int ExistenciaDeUsuario(string Usuario)
{
using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConexionBD))
{
Conn.Open();
using (MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT
                                                   count(usuario)
                                                   FROM
                                                       tb_usuario
                                                   WHERE
                                                       usuario = @usuario", Conn))
           {
                Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", Usuario);
                Int32 existe = (Int32)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return existe;
            }
    }


}
```

Luego consultas la función de manera más sencilla

`if(ExistenciaDeUsuario(textBox.Text) > 0 { //tu código }`

Saludos, espero que te sea últil

Comment: Intente con tu método y de igual manera me funciono